# email validation not working in update form using laravel validation

Tags: laravel

```
$id = $request->id;
$validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'email' => 'unique:customers,email,'.$request->id
]);
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? You're checking for unique email except the user with the given id. You're making use of validator, for it to work you need to manually check if the validation fails or passes and handle it appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a custom validator. You need to handle the validation failure manually. Also your code checks for unique email in the table `customers` except for the email of the user `$request->id`. I assume this is intended.

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email' => 'email|unique:customers,email,' . $request->id
]);

if ($validator->fails())  {
    // Handle failure
}
```

The code below will automatically handle validation failure and redirect back with errors and inputs.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'email|unique:customers,email,' . $request->id
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('customers')->ignore($customer->id),
    ],
]);
```